# Http 404 NOT FOUND error - Apache Solr

Tags: python, solr

I am trying to crawl a set of web pages and index them using Apache Solr. To crawl the web pages, I am using python with the help of BeautifulSoup and urllib2. I successfully retrieved the urls and the html data.

Now I am trying to get Solr to index them via solr(http://code.google.com/p/solrpy/). I keep getting a Http 404 error NOT FOUND.

I haven't modified the default schema.xml and I'm using the example server that comes with Apache Solr.

Here s my code:

```
import sys 
import urllib2
import solr
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import hashlib
solrUrl = 'http://localhost:8983/solr/'
solrInstance = solr.SolrConnection(solrUrl)
conn = urllib2.urlopen('http://seekingalpha.com/market_currents.xml')   
root = etree.fromstring(conn.read())
links = root.findall(".//link")
counter = 0
for link in links:
    counter=counter+1
    url = link.text 
    url_md5 = hashlib.md5(url).hexdigest()
    conn = urllib2.urlopen(link.text)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(conn.read())
    title_page = soup.html.head.title.string.decode("utf-8")
    print title_page
    try: # Add to the Solr instance
        solrInstance.add(id=str(url_md5),url_s=url,text=str(title_page),title=str(title_page))
    except Exception as inst:
        print "Error adding URL: "+url
        print "\tWith Message: "+str(inst)
    else:
        print "Added Page \""+title+"\" with URL "+url
try:
    solrInstance.commit()
except:
    print "Could not Commit Changes to Solr Instance - check logs"
else:
    print "Success. "+str(counter)+" documents added to index"
```

And here's the error:

```
Error adding URL: http://seekingalpha.com/currents/all
    With Message: HTTP code=404, reason=Not Found
```

How do I rectify this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any reason you are not using Apache Nutch? It is designed for crawling and has direct support for Solr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used `solrpy` myself but after playing around with it, it appears you must remove the trailing `/` in your solr URL. Change it to

`solrUrl = 'http://localhost:8983/solr'`

Comment: It worked! Thanks. One small backslash, spent two hours trying debug it!